# How to save glm result without data or only with coeffients for prediction?

Tags: r, prediction, glm

When I use the following R code,

```
model_glm=glm(V1~. , data=xx,family="binomial");
save(file="modelfile",model_glm);
```

The size of modelfile will be as much as the data, which will be 1gig in my case. How can I remove the data part in the result of model_glm, so I can only save a small file.

Comment: Set `model = FALSE` in your call to `glm` to prevent the model.frame from being returned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting `model = FALSE` in your call to `glm` should prevent the `model.frame` from being returned. Also setting `y = FALSE` will prevent the response vector from being returned. `x = FALSE` is the default setting and prevents the `model.matrix` from being returned.

This combination should shrink the size of your glm object.

Of course, you can also extract the coefficients with `coef(model_glm)` or, with standard errors,

```
summary(model_glm)$coef
```

Comment: Have you looked at resulting model? It is still very heavy: residuals, fitted values and the full qr matrix.  The `biglm` package returns much lighter model objects.

Comment: Yes, the `bigglm` function may be a viable alternative. If you post it an an answer, it'd get a vote from me. Nonetheless, it's still possible to select only the desired components from the `glm` object before saving.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue where I was running the GLM as part of an R in production and the size of the GLM greatly slowed me down.  I found I needed to kill off more than just the `$data`.  [Here](http://datasciencethoughts.blogspot.com/2014/12/r-in-production-diaries-glm-trap-part-2.html) is my post on it, with an example below.

```
> object.size(sg)
96499472 bytes
> sg$residuals <- NULL
> sg$weights <- NULL
> sg$fitted.values <- NULL
> sg$prior.weights <- NULL
> sg$na.action<- NULL
> sg$linear.predictors <- NULL
> sg$fitted.values <- NULL
> sg$effects <-NULL
> sg$data <- NULL
> object.size(sg)
3483976 bytes
> sg$qr$qr <- NULL
> object.size(sg)
79736 bytes
```

Comment: Just a comment... In your blog you can barely read the things highlighted in yellow

Comment: You could also do something like `sg[c("residuals", "weights", "fitted.values")] <- NULL` where you make that vector include the names of everything you want to get rid of.

Comment: @RichardScriven Oh my - it burned my eyes.

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks, fixed, good thing I'm not in data vis.

Answer (score 1):

`object.size()` is misleading because it ignores the environment attributes. 
If you want to assess the true size, use:

```
length(serialize(model_glm, NULL))
```

Apart from the data stored, if you want to significantly reduce the size of your glm do:

```
rm(list=ls(envir = attr(model_glm$terms, ".Environment")),
     envir = attr(model_glm$terms,
              ".Environment"))
```

This comes from a well detailed [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/r/is-the-size-of-your-lm-model-causing-you-headaches)

Answer (score 0):

You can NULL the data in the model object before saving it.  I did a quick test and still generated predictions.

```
model_glm$data <- NULL
```